# java.lang.runtimeexception unable to start activity componentinfo android.view.inflateexception

Tags: android

i am trying to open activity Setting.java from action bar item itemSetting..
using Intent. i have registered both activities already..on click of itemSetting it throw error..
activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/d10"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/ten_closehihat" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/d3"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/d8"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/three_openhihat" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/d11"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/d10"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/elevan_china" />

    <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/d4"
       android:layout_width="250dp"
       android:layout_height="250dp"
       android:layout_alignTop="@+id/d5"
       android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/d6"
       android:scaleType="centerInside"
       android:src="@drawable/four_midtom" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/d7"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/d8"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/seven_floortom" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/d2"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/d5"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/d10"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/two_ride" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/d8"
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="190dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/d2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/eight_crash" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/d5"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/d3"
        android:layout_marginRight="39dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/d7"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/five_hitom" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/d6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/six_bassdrum" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/d1"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/d9"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/d7"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/one_snare" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/d9"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/nine_crash" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.mydrum;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ImageView d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6, d7, d8, d9, d10, d11;
MediaPlayer mp;
final Context context = this;
Intent i;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    d1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.d1);
    d2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.d2);
    d3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.d3);
    d4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.d4);
    d5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.d5);
    d6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.d6);
    d7 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.d7);
    d8 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.d8);
    d9 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.d9);
    d10 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.d10);
    d11 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.d11);
    d1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.snare);
            if (mp != null) {

                mp.start();
            }

            mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    mp.release();
                }
            });
        }
    });

    d2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.ride);
            if (mp != null) {

                mp.start();
            }

            mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    mp.release();
                }
            });
        }
    });
    d3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),
                    R.raw.openhihat);
            if (mp != null) {

                mp.start();
            }

            mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    mp.release();
                }
            });
        }
    });
    d4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.midtom);
            if (mp != null) {

                mp.start();
            }

            mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    mp.release();
                }
            });
        }
    });
    d5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.hitom);
            if (mp != null) {

                mp.start();
            }

            mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    mp.release();
                }
            });
        }
    });
    d6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mp = MediaPlayer
                    .create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.bassdrum);
            if (mp != null) {

                mp.start();
            }

            mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    mp.release();
                }
            });
        }
    });
    d7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mp = MediaPlayer
                    .create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.floortom);
            if (mp != null) {

                mp.start();
            }

            mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    mp.release();
                }
            });
        }
    });
    d8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.crash2);
            if (mp != null) {

                mp.start();
            }

            mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    mp.release();
                }
            });
        }
    });
    d9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.crash);
            if (mp != null) {

                mp.start();
            }

            mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    mp.release();
                }
            });
        }
    });
    d10.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),
                    R.raw.closehihat);
            if (mp != null) {

                mp.start();
            }

            mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    mp.release();
                }
            });
        }
    });
    d11.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.china);
            if (mp != null) {

                mp.start();
            }

            mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    mp.release();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater m = getMenuInflater();
    m.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.itemSetting:
        i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Setting.class);
        startActivity(i);
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}
`
custom_setting.xml

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnReset"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="160dp"
    android:src="@drawable/reset" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnMove"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/btnReset"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/btnReset"
    android:src="@drawable/move" />

</RelativeLayout>

Setting.java
package com.example.mydrum;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class Setting extends Activity {
ImageButton btnMove, btnReset;

// android:theme="?android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog"
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.custom_setting);
    btnMove = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnMove);
    btnReset = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnReset);
}

}

menifest.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.mydrum"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.mydrum.Setting"
         >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>



menu -> main.xml
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.mydrum.MainActivity" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/itemSetting"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Setting"
    android:icon="@drawable/setting"/>

</menu>
```

plz provide the solution..
thank you in advance

log cat

```
02-03 13:31:20.891: W/dalvikvm(1937): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
02-03 13:31:20.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1937): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-03 13:31:20.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1937): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mydrum/com.example.mydrum.Setting}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>
02-03 13:31:20.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1937):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
02-03 13:31:20.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1937):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
02-03 13:31:20.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1937):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
02-03 13:31:20.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1937):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
02-03 13:31:20.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1937):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-03 13:31:20.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1937):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-03 13:31:20.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1937):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
02-03 13:31:20.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1937):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-03 13:31:20.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1937):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-03 13:31:20.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1937):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-03 13:31:20.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1937):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-03 13:31:20.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1937):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-03 13:31:20.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1937): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>
02-03 13:31:20.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1937):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
02-03 13:31:20.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1937):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
02-03 13:31:20.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1937):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
02-03 13:31:20.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1937):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
02-03 13:31:20.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1937):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
02-03 13:31:20.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1937):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
02-03 13:31:20.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1937):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
02-03 13:31:20.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1937):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
02-03 13:31:20.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1937):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
02-03 13:31:20.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1937):     at com.example.mydrum.Setting.onCreate(Setting.java:15)
02-03 13:31:20.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1937):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
02-03 13:31:20.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1937):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
02-03 13:31:20.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1937):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
02-03 13:31:20.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1937):     ... 11 more
02-03 13:31:20.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1937): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-03 13:31:20.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1937):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
02-03 13:31:20.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1937):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
02-03 13:31:20.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1937):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
02-03 13:31:20.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1937):     ... 23 more
02-03 13:31:20.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1937): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
02-03 13:31:20.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1937):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
02-03 13:31:20.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1937):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:483)
02-03 13:31:20.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1937):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:351)
02-03 13:31:20.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1937):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:773)
02-03 13:31:20.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1937):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1937)
02-03 13:31:20.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1937):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
02-03 13:31:20.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1937):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2780)
02-03 13:31:20.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1937):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2717)
02-03 13:31:20.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1937):     at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:379)
02-03 13:31:20.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1937):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:174)
02-03 13:31:20.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1937):     ... 26 more
```

Comment: can you share your logcat information?

Comment: show logcat information...

Answer (score 0):

If MainActivity and Setting both are in same package

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mydrum"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Setting"
         >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: you are getting  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError too. can you post the custom_setting xml and full Setting.class code

Comment: i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Setting.class); why are you using getApplicationContext to start an activity? use this instead